# How can I get the this ruby script to output the same rows and columns as another CSV file and add another column to it?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

The goal of this script is to generate usernames for the useradd linux command. I also want to have the names same names in the same order be put into a new CSV file with the newly generated names and passwords.

As of now I have the script to generate the new names by reading the the CSV file.

The CSV file's first two rows look like this.

```
first_name, last_name
Briana, Considine
```

This is the part of the script that works:

```
filename = 'employeedata.csv'

CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
   first_name_char = row['first_name'].strip.split('')
   useradd_name = "#{row['last_name']}#{first_name_char.first}#{first_name_char.last}"
   password = ""; 8.times{value << ((rand(2)==1?65:97) + rand(25)).chr}
   system("useradd '#{useradd_name}'")
   puts useradd_name
   puts password
```

This is the part of the scripts that errors out.

```
   CSV.open("GeneratedUsers.csv", "w") do |outfile|
        outfile << ["First Name", "Last Name:", "Username:"] #to make the new headers
        outfile << "#{row['first_name']}" #import firstname from employeedata.csv
   end
end
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        17: from Nick_Hyder_Project3.rb:19:in `<main>'
        16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:509:in `foreach'
        15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:657:in `open'
        14: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:510:in `block in foreach'
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:303:in `parse'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:779:in `parse_quotable_loose'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:31:in `block in each_line'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:827:in `block in parse_quotable_loose'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:1078:in `emit_row'
         4: from Nick_Hyder_Project3.rb:25:in `block in <main>'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:657:in `open'
         2: from Nick_Hyder_Project3.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1186:in `<<'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/writer.rb:37:in `<<': undefined method `collect' for "Briana":String (NoMethodError)
```

Is there a way to copy all of the old file before I add the new usernames and passwords into new columns? Or do I need to write the new CSV row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows for CSV data need to be arrays. So this line:

```
  outfile << "#{row['first_name']}"
```

Should be:

```
  outfile << [row['first_name']]
```

However since you probably want to add several rows, you should rearrange your loop code to open the output file first, and then process the input rows:

```
CSV.open("GeneratedUsers.csv", "w") do |outfile|
  # Headers for outfile
  outfile << ["First Name", "Last Name:", "Username:"] 

  # Process users
  CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
    ...code to add user etc...
    ...
    # Append new user to outfile
    outfile << [row['first_name'], row['last_name'], useradd_name]
  end
end
```

Comment: This does fix the error, but when I do this it only writes the last name for the CSV file. Do I need to reorder the code so that it does all of names?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSV file that adds columns to an existing CSV file as follows.

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def add_cols(csv_fname_in, csv_fname_out, new_cols)
  new_col_headers, *new_col_bodies = new_cols.transpose
  new_col_bodies = new_col_bodies.transpose
  header_written = false
  CSV.open(csv_fname_out, 'w') do |csv_out|
    CSV.foreach(csv_fname_in, headers:true) do |csv_in|
      if header_written == false
        headers_in = csv_in.headers              
        csv_out << headers_in + new_col_headers
        header_written = true
      end
      csv_out << csv_in.values_at(*headers_in) + new_col_bodies.shift
    end
  end
end
```

See [CSV::Row#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-values_at).

**Example**

Let's create an input file.

```
str =<<~END
first_name,last_name
Briana,Considine
Mack,Truck
END
```

```
fname_in  = 'in.csv'
```

```
File.write(fname_in, str)
  #=> 49
```

Confirm the file was written correctly.

```
puts File.read(fname_in)
first_name,last_name
Briana,Considine
Mack,Truck
```

Now create the output file:

```
fname_out = 'out.csv'
new_cols = [['age', 22, 110], ['iq', 85, 140]]
add_cols(fname_in, fname_out, new_cols)
```

Confirm the output file was written correctly.

```
puts File.read(fname_out)
first_name,last_name,age,iq
Briana,Considine,22,110
Mack,Truck,85,140
```

Note:

```
new_col_headers, *new_col_bodies = new_cols.transpose
  #=> [["age", "iq"], [22, 85], [110, 140]]
new_col_headers
  #=> ["age", "iq"] 
new_col_bodies
  #=> [[22, 85], [110, 140]] 
new_col_bodies = new_col_bodies.transpose
  #=> [[22, 110], [85, 140]]
```